# how access returned values from client side and display them

Tags: javascript, html, puppeteer

I was experimenting with puppeteer and I built a simple scraper that gets information from youtube and it works fine what I was trying to add was to display that scraped information on my web page with `<p>` tags. Is there any way to do this? Where I'm am stuck is my `name` and `avatarUrl` variables are inside my scrape function as a local variable so how can I get those values and insert them in my `<p>` tag. For a rough sketch of what I tried, I did:  `document.getElementById('nameId')=name;` after importing my js script(on HTML side) but this wont work because `name` is a local variable and it can't be accessed outside the scope. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeChannel(url) {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse/div[3]/ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer/tp-yt-app-header-layout/div/tp-yt-app-header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ytd-channel-name/div/div/yt-formatted-string');
  const text = await el.getProperty('textContent');
  const name = await text.jsonValue();

  const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="img"]');
  const src = await el2.getProperty('src');
  const avatarURL = await src.jsonValue();

  browser.close();
  console.log({
    name,
    avatarlURL
  })
  return {
    name,
    avatarURL
  }
}


scrapeChannel('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQOtt1RZbIbBqXhRa9-RB5g')

module.exports = {
  scrapeChannel,
}
```

```html
<body onload="scrapeChannel()">

  <p id="nameId">'put the scraped name here'</p>
  <p id="avatarUrlId">'put the scraped avatar url here'</p>
  <!--
document.getElementById('nameId')=name;
document.getElementById('avatartUrlId')=avatarURL;
-->
</body>
```

Comment: So you are trying to display the scrapped data on your front end? show us your router code if you have written one?

Comment: yes both the name and the avatar URL @ksa

Comment: Have you set any routes?

Comment: sorry i can't handle it

Comment: no i haven't set any routes @ksa

Comment: You need to set routers so that you can access the backend data from your frontend. Something like this  ```const router = require("express").Router();
const {scrapeChannel} = require("path to scrapeChannel"){
``` 
 router.route("/").get(async (req, res) => { 
const output = await scrapeChannel()  
return res.json(output)})

Comment: Then from your frontend do this fetch("http://localhost:5000/").then(res => {res.json()})

Comment: how am I gonna call the variables after setting the route on the front end@ksa

Comment: you have to use ```fetch("backendurl").then(res => {res.json()})```.  e,g ```backendurl =http://localhost:5000/``` . once you do this, request is sent to the backend URL that ends with ```/```.

Comment: when you said "path to scrape Channel" you mean the path to the whole js file right. And can you please add your answer below? I think there is an error in your router code. @ksa

Comment: yes. whole js file.

Comment: I have added my answer below.

Comment: yeah im reviewing it now@ksa

Comment: Sorry, Are you using Vanilla JS in the frontend?

Comment: yes I'm using vanilla js on front end@ksa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used [**cheerio**](https://cheerio.js.org/) in one of my projects and this is what I did in the backend and in the front end.

**Node & Express JS Backend**

In order to access your backend from the frontend, you need to set Routes in your backend. All your frontend requests are redirected to these routes. For more information read this [Express Routes](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html).

**E.g Route.js code**

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const { callscrapeChannel } = require("../scrape-code/scrape");

router.route("/scrapedata").get(async (req, res) => {
  const Result = await callscrapeChannel();
  return res.json(Result);
});

module.exports = router;
```

**scrapeChannel.js file**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function scrapeChannel(url) {

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);

  const [el] = await page.$x('/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse/div[3]/ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer/tp-yt-app-header-layout/div/tp-yt-app-header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/ytd-channel-name/div/div/yt-formatted-string');
  const text = await el.getProperty('textContent');
  const name = await text.jsonValue();

  const [el2] = await page.$x('//*[@id="img"]');
  const src = await el2.getProperty('src');
  const avatarURL = await src.jsonValue();

  browser.close();
  console.log({
    name,
    avatarURL
  })
  return {
    name,
    avatarURL
  }
}

async function callscrapeChannel() {
const data = await scrapeChannel('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCQOtt1RZbIbBqXhRa9-RB5g')
return data
}


module.exports = {
 callscrapeChannel,
}
```

in your **server.js** file

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const scrapeRoute = require("./Routes/routes");
require("dotenv").config({ debug: process.env.DEBUG });
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use("/api", scrapeRoute);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is running on port: http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**dependencies you need (package.json)**

```
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "esm": "^3.2.25",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "puppeteer": "^8.0.0"
  }
```

**Frontend**

In the front-end, I have used [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). You need to send a get request to your backend. All you have to do is

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script>
   async function callScrapeData(){
      await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/scrapedata`)
    .then((res) => { 
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       setTimeout(()=> {
        resolve(res.json())
       }, 1000)
     })
        
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
document.getElementById("nameId").innerHTML = response.name
document.getElementById("avatartUrlId").innerHTML = response.avatarURL
}

)
    }

  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <h1>scrape</h1>
      <p id="nameId"></p>
      <p id="avatartUrlId"></p>
      <button onclick="callScrapeData()">click</button>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Remember, my backend server is running on port 5000**

**output**
[image: output]

The above code is just an example and I have modified it to fit your question. I hope this helps you to some extent. It's straightforward. Let me know if you have any questions.

Note: I assume you have a server.js file in your backend and it is configured properly.

Comment: I'm getting an error ```identifier 'scrapeChannel' has already been declared```@ksa

Comment: backend? or in frontend?

Comment: at the backend @ksa

Comment: I have edited my answers again. Not sure how you are implementing these codes.

Comment: i basically did everything you did except wrap my await axios with an async function and called that function on page load but I'm getting the error ```Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404```
    at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10)
    at e.exports (isAxiosError.js:10)
    at XMLHttpRequest.l.onreadystatechange (isAxiosError.js:10) @ksa

Comment: the only thing in my server.js the is directly connected to scraping is the router code everything else is linked to different functions that don't apply to scrapping. @ksa

Comment: I have added server.js code to my answer. Routes need to be configured in the server.js file. If you do this right then that should fix the error.

Comment: yeah, same error. I can live share my code with you if you would like @ksa

Comment: I am working at the moment. I will ping sometimes after work. Till then please keep trying.

Comment: yes, I will keep trying, I will keep an eye on stack overflow for your ping@ksa

Comment: I replicated your project in my local machine and it works perfectly fine. I have edited my answer and please go through the entire answer once again. All you have to do is copy and paste the code to your project and change the path name accordingly in your backend. compare your server.js with the above one and replace the lines that are necessary.

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks so much. Turns out there was a port blocker active on port 5000 created by code intrusion AI. It was blocking all data transfer on port 5000 it thought it was a threat. Any way fixed that and your code worked like a charm. Thanks again! @ksa

Comment: Happy to know. @anon10023108